How do I ask `pip` to use the system certificates?
My organisation recently updated certificates on my pc after which pip stopped working. I cannot get to any pypi package. I get the following error
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))
One workaround i found was to use the --use-feature=truststore option which is currently Experimental on pip. This fails as well because most of the subsequent setup commands that pip uses to install dependencies of a package still fail with the same error.
example:
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/setuptools/
Can someone please assist me on how i can ask pip to use the default certificates on my Windows(11) PC ?
I took a look at relavant questions on this community, but nothing actually helped but this (partly)..
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/https-certificates/#
Also I can ping pypi.python.org


The following question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

I have come accross it. :) Thanks. I couldnt find an answer there.
